# sql запрос с join

Tags: sql, join

Есть таблички:

```
cosmonauts: 
  id, 
  full_name(text), 
  birthdate(datetime), 
  country_id, 
  can_be_pilot(true/false), 
  rank(number)

tasks: 
  id, 
  title(text), 
  description(text), 
  deadline(datetime)

cosmonauts_schedule: 
  id, 
  cosmonaut_id, 
  task_id, 
  starts_at(datetime)
```

Нужно ​ ​выбрать ​ ​того, ​ ​кто ​ ​умеет​ ​пилотировать ​ ​корабль, ​ ​и ​ ​у​ ​кого ​ ​есть ​ ​полностью​ ​свободный ​ ​от​ ​задач день в течении недели с сегодняшнего дня.

```
select id 
  from cosmonauts c
  join cosmonauts_schedule cs on cs.cosmonaut_id = c.id
  join tasks t on t.id = cs.task_id
  where can_be_pilot = true and
```

Comment: уточните, что лежит в task.deadline и cosmonauts_schedule.start_as. Если я правильно понял, то в cosmonauts_schedule.start_as дата начала задания, а в task.deadline дата конца задания? И если это учебное задание, с какого-то сайта, будет здорово если вы скинете ссылку, есть идея, но не уверен, что она работает как надо.

Comment: @Виктор вы все правильно поняли по полям таблиц. Задание скинул товарищ(ему его давали на собеседовании), но я никак не могу решить его, уже терпение кончилось, поэтому обратился за помощью

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
select *
  from cosmonauts C
  left join (
    select distinct S.cosmonaut_id
      from cosmonauts_schedule S
      join tasks T on T.id=S.task_id
     where S.starts_at < NOW()+INTERVAL 7 DAY
       and T.deadtime  >= NOW()
  ) D on D.cosmonaut_id=C.id
 where C.can_be_pilot=TRUE and D.cosmonaut_id IS NULL
```

Сначала делаем подзапрос, в котором получаем список космонавтов, задачи которых начинаются ранее чем на следующей неделе (если позже, они нас не интересуют) и при этом еще не окончились на текущий день.

А дальше у нас несколько вариантов, либо как в вышепоказанном запросе подклеиваем по `LEFT JOIN` и убеждаемся, что ничего не подклеилось (`D.cosmonaut_id IS NULL`). Либо используем такой же подзапрос в виде `NOT IN`, либо его же, немного измененный, в `NOT EXISTS` (что конкретно использовать зависит только от целей оптимизации в той или иной ситуации).

P.S. функция `now()` и конструкция `interval` присутствует не во всех диалектах SQL, в конкретной СУБД может потребоваться найти равноценную замену.